# Can the heat be calculated in a DC voltage drop circuit?

Tags: resistors, heat, power-dissipation

Can the heat be calculated in a DC voltage drop circuit? 24 V, 150 Ω, ~100 mA. The first resistor was 1/2 W, the new one is 5 W. We want to know the expected heat for the new resistor. Looking to predict the temperature (in °F) that should be seen in the circuit.

Comment: Do you want to calculate heating power or temperature?

Comment: also you can't have 24V 150Ω 100mA all at the same time in a resistor - that's not possible. The resistance is 240Ω or the current is 160mA or the voltage is 15V.

Comment: On the face of it, the heat power will be the same. Note that temperature and heat are not the same.

Comment: Looking to predict the temperature (in F) that should be seen in the circuit.

Comment: Often you will find a temperature rise vs. power dissipation in the device's specification sheet.